# ASP.net MVC3 . View page. getting errors because can't implicitly convert type list<school> to 'school; HELP please

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc-3, list

I get an error on my  View page thats says:

Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List' to 'SchoolAdministrator.SchoolAdminProductionServices.SchoolTypeRef'

I want to know how come Im getting these errors. I believe I am doing everything right

Controller

```
 [SchoolAuthorizeAttribute(AdminRoles = "ViewSchoolTypeRef")]
    public ActionResult ViewSchoolType()
    {
        try
        {
            Guid SchoolTypeRefId = Request["SchoolTypeRefId"] != null ? new Guid(Request["SchoolTypeRefId"]) : Guid.Empty;
            ViewBag.merchantTypeRef = SchoolAdministrator.Models.SchoolAdminProduction.SchoolTypeRef.LoadSchoolTypeRef(SchoolTypeRefId, string.Empty, string.Empty, string.Empty);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Commons.ErrorHandling.ReportError("SchoolAdministrator.Controllers.SchoolController ViewSchoolType",e);
        }
        return View();
    }
```

Model

```
    public class SchoolTypeRef
{
    /// <summary>
    /// This function allows us to load the School types if parametrs are empty, else load a single user by their ID 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="SchoolTypeRef">The merchant type ref id, unique ID</param>
    /// <param name="name">name of the School type</param>
    /// <param name="description">description of the School type</param>
    /// <returns>List of all users or list of a single user</returns>
      public static List<SchoolAdminProductionServices.SchoolTypeRef> LoadSchoolTypeRef(Guid SchoolTypeRef, string name, string description, string fdrSchoolTypeCode)
    {
        try
        {
            SchoolAdminProductionServices.SchoolAdminProductionServicesSoapClient client = new SchoolAdminProductionServices.SchoolAdminProductionServicesSoapClient();
            return client.LoadSchoolTypeRef(SchoolTypeRef, name, description, fdrSchoolTypeCode).ToList<SchoolAdminProductionServices.SchoolTypeRef>();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        { 
            Commons.ErrorHandling.ReportError("SchoolTypeRef.LoadSchoolTypeRef()",e);
        }
        return new List<SchoolAdminProductionServices.SchoolTypeRef>();
    }
   }
```

View
 THIS IS WHERE THE ERROR OCCURRED BETWEEN THE <% %>

```
   <%SchoolAdministrator.DarkstarAdminProductionServices.SchoolTypeRefmerchantTypeRef =
          ViewBag.SchoolTypeRef ??
            new SchoolAdministrator.SchoolAdminProductionServices.SchoolTypeRef();%>
<table>
 <tr>
       <td colspan="2" class="tableHeader"> School Type Ref Details</td>
   </tr> 
   tr>
       td class="label"> Name:</td>
       td class="content"><%=SchoolTypeRef.name%></td>
   /tr>
    tr>
       td class="label"> Description:</td>
       td class="content"><%=SchoolTypeRef.description%></td>
   /tr>
    tr>
       td class="label"> FDR SchoolType Code:</td>
       td class="content"><%=SchoolTypeRef.fdrSchoolTypeCode%></td>
  /tr>
/table>
```

Comment: yeah i tried putting it into a list like so   <%List<SchoolAdministrator.DarkstarAdminProductionServices.SchoolTypeRef> merchantTypeRef =  ViewBag.SchoolTypeRef ?? new List<SchoolAdministrator.SchoolAdminProductionServices.SchoolTypeRef>();%>

Comment: `ViewBag.merchantTypeRef != ViewBag.SchoolTypeRef`

Comment: Inshallah, I will try it

Comment: error on merchant suppsoe to be School ..sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your web service call is returning a List<> of schoolRefTypes, but your view is trying to access the list as if it were a single instance of schoolRefTypes. Instead of assigning a list of schoolRefTypes to the viewbag, assign just one. A quick way to do this is use the .First() method to get the first element on the list. I'd imagine though you'd want to somehow restrict it to a specific schoolRefType based on the MVC convention of ID or something.

Comment: thanks u gave me a big hit..i end up using the firstordefault()..thanks

Answer (score 0):

List is a generic list. School is your custom object. The asp.net simply cannot convert from your type to a generic list of your type. You should try to check if the list is not empty and then access to the elements.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
<%SchoolAdministrator.DarkstarAdminProductionServices.SchoolTypeRefmerchantTypeRef =     ViewBag.SchoolTypeRef ?? new     SchoolAdministrator.SchoolAdminProductionServices.SchoolTypeRef();%>
```

to

```
<%SchoolAdministrator.DarkstarAdminProductionServices.SchoolTypeRefmerchantTypeRef SchoolTypeRef =     ViewBag.SchoolTypeRef ?? new     SchoolAdministrator.SchoolAdminProductionServices.SchoolTypeRef();%>
```